# Best approach to creating a task in Salesforce based on Email Click - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

We are building a journey in which we are sending an email with a Question.

Instead of linking to a survey (e.g. CloudPage), to keep it simple, we thought the best way is to ask the question in the email.

Based on the survey response (click) we should:

- Reply A: Create a task for Salesforce agent #1; and exit journey
- Reply B: Create 1 task for Salesforce agents #1 and #2; and exit journey
- Wait 14 days - if no reply - move to next step in journey.

What's the best approach to achieve this?

We thought to design email clicks to redirect to a CloudPage and use AmpScript on the page to:

1. Create the task
2. Update the criteria to match exit criteria

Is this the right approach?

Any interesting alternatives?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach - I would also add a separate data extension to log all clicks and potential errors (contact not found in Salesforce; connector issue, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you're suggesting sounds like a valid one. You can do this without any code, though, by using a couple of engagement splits to test whether the contact clicked on Link A or Link B and then use a Task Activity to create a new task in CRM and an Update Contact activity to manipulate data to match your exit criteria. I'm not sure this last step would be particularly necessary as you already have these contacts going down separate branches that could lead to nowhere (Journey Exit).

If you want to create your task in Sales Cloud immediately following the response (click through), your suggested approach would be the way to go, either using AMPScript in the Landing Page to create tasks directly using CreateSalesForceObject() AMPScript or by injecting your contacts into a second Journey using a REST API call from the landing page to do Task/Contact activities and execute any further comms needed to be sent to the Contact.

Comment: Thank you @Macca, we have considered the multiple engagement splits - but since the waiting period is 14 days - assuming we don't want to lose more than a day after reply to survey - it means 13 additional engagement splits, am I correct or am I missing something? Not very elegant and potential room for errors because of quantity, but doable. Knowing this, would you still follow the "no code" approach?

Comment: If you want to create your tasks etc immediately on click through, your approach seems like a good one to me. I've updated my response, but I don't think it really adds to your solution. It's the way many of us would address the requirements.

Comment: Have you considered the Interactive Email feature? This would allow doing without the coding of a landing page as it directly injects responses into a data extension that you can use for a journey to create the SFDC tasks. To cover your fallback version you can create a content block with a button that has the view_email_url string in it. This leads to the browser version where the interactive form works for those people as well.

Comment: @StephandePaly. Yes. You could do that, also. My understanding was that the OP wants to create the tasks in near realtime. But, yes, there are many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Yes, that's what always makes it tricky. With two automations running at full and half hour you get it down to half an hour offset at max. With halfway decent AMPscript skills you better use the solution you suggested yourself. Just be aware that it costs you an extra supermessage

Comment: Thank you @StephandePaly, interesting approach! I am just skeptical (can read ignorant) about this new shiny feature released not too long ago; Don't like to be among the firsts to test it - especially with different email clients in mind (e.g. Outlook 2013, 2016, etc.); don't have the resources to experiment and rework in case of a problem. But definitely worth a vote-up! Thanks

Comment: @Macca,
The injection to a new Journey with REST API is very interesting - as they could eventually "continue" the journey after the task is created.
But then we could use the AMPscript scenario to inject them as well.

Is there one solution that is more robust than the other? (i.e. AMPScript vs. REST API)? What are my options to catch (and retry) if either fails?

Comment: @Macca, if the question was best approach to create a SF Task based on File Download (e.g. PDF), and not Email Click. What would I need to change? Do I have to host the link to the file on a Landing Page to fire AmpScript based on click? Or is there a way to link directly to the PDF file in the Email AND trigger AMPscript to create the SF task? I am also posting this as a different question, since there could be public interest.

Comment: Again, it's a question of whether you want to create the tasks in realtime, I think. For an Automation, you could inject into Journey Builder based on the _Click data view with SQL or a filtered DE using a Measure based on click throughs. For a realtime setup, yes, I'd probably go down your route of linking to a landing page that does your CreateSingleSalesforceObject() call and then does a Redirect() to the location of your pdf.

Comment: @Macca, AMPscript Redirect! Genious! Also, liked the approach for a near-real-time automation, though not sure it's less effort than that LP + Ampscript. Thank you so much!

Comment: PS
@Macca Did you mean CreateSalesforceObject? I can't find CreateSingleSalesforceObject() in the doc.

Comment: Correct. Sorry. A typo.