# Best Approach for tracking File downloads and Triggering AmpScript on File Download (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

We are creating a Journey in which we want to create a SF Task after a file was Downloaded.

This is a typical B2B scenario, and can easily be achieved with Pardot.

But what's the best approach to achieve this in **Marketing Cloud**?

- Where to host the file? (PDF)
- If hosted in Content Builder, can we trigger AmpScript when it's accessed?
- Assuming the email to incite for the PDF download is sent in Journey Builder - is there a way to generate a personalized link in such a way it will trigger AMPScript to create a Task for the Contact Owner (One-click experience AND recipient doesn't leave his email inbox to get the file); or do we have to send the subscriber to a landing page where AMPscript will run on a click on a second click to download the pdf?

Thanks for your help!

Edited:

**Clarifying:** Business (Sales Reps) want to be notified ASAP for the file download, which is why we can't use an Engagement Decision + SF Action to create the Task all in Journey Builder.

**Related Question:**

[Best approach to creating a task in Salesforce based on Email Click - Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307792/best-approach-to-creating-a-task-in-salesforce-based-on-email-click-marketing)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer doing this in Salesforce rather than in Marketing Cloud if the PDF is dynamic.

If the file is static with no dynamic fields inside your PDF then you can host the pdf inside marketing cloud content builder and show a link pointing to [CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/) where you can host a PDF file. CloudpagesURL ampscript function can able to capture customers subscriber key in cloud page and use [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) function to create a task.

But if the file is dynamic then you can create a [sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&type=5)/community in salesforce and point a link with additonal variables in URL. Then you can use lightning components / VF page to render the PDF and you can create a task in salesforce itself.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: very helpful, yes. 
The PDF is Static (same file for everyone). What do you mean by "host the file on CloudPageURL"? Is that what I describe in the second option? Meaning - a click in the email will not start the download in the inbox, right? The Subscriber will be redirected to a Cloud Page where a link to the PDF hosted on content builder will be present. So 2 clicks. or is there a way to start download on page load? what am I missing?

Comment: Of course, I could use JS to start download on page load... trying to see if there is a more elegant way to do this. Especially as if JS is turned off client-side this wouldn't work - so we're back to 2-clicks.

Comment: Just realized (Thanks to @Macca) I can also use Redirect to the PDF URL on the Landing page instead of JS. So we have a viable - 1-click solution (that will load the Landing Page, then trigger AmpsScript to Task creation and Redirect to PDF file. Great! Back to the original question: Can I do this without a Landing Page? (i.e. Trigger AmpScript when the PDF URL is visited?

Comment: @LimeWeb unfortunately that's not possible. Marketing Cloud lacks the Pardot capability to listen on interactions with content elements. The Cloudpage with the redirect to the PDF URL is the most viable solution.

Comment: @LimeWeb unfortunately, without a landing page  or salesforce sites which will be a landing page. You can't track in marketing cloud/salesforce just by using PDF URL.